# photo upload Jquery script not working in chrome & ie?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

i have following function to upload photo on facebook with jquery and ajax

```
unction _upCover(imgURL) {
    $('#uploadb').hide(0);
        $('#uploadb2').show(0);
     var postMSG="";
 var url='https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token='+accessToken+"&message="+postMSG;

 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("url",imgURL);

  $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',

                   success: function(data){
                                             $('#uploadb2').slideUp("slow");
                                             $('#changecover').slideDown("slow");
                                                     }
                });

}
```

This is working fine in firefox brwoser
but when i run it in chrome and ie
it works but

```
success: function(data)
```

This function dose not work 
anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are mis-using the `contentType` paremeter. As [detailed on the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),

> contentType 
>   Default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
> When
>   sending data to the server, use this content-type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", which is fine for most cases. If
>   you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax() then it'll always be
>   sent to the server (even if no data is sent). Data will always be
>   transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you must decode this
>   appropriately on the server side.

As you see the contentType parameter is used to detail the content type of the request.  You passed a `false` value - I am unsure what behavior this will affect - but I am sure that you are not supposed to pass a boolean value there.  **Try leaving that parameter out.**

Comment: i tried it and script didnt work if i change it or remove it. in chrome and ie it is also uploading the photo to the user's profile but success: function(data) is not working?